# Firebase providerData passed in props, trouble accessing in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-props

Using Firebase and able to pass the providerData into props.

Although when passing to another component I'm unable to fetch from the array in the componentDidMount.

I'm stuck on trying to show user's email with: `console.log(this.state.providerData[0].email )`

Getting `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

[image]

This is for a create-react-app; trying to grab user's id to run further ajax commands.

App.js

```
// React core.
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// Firebase.
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import StyledFirebaseAuth from 'react-firebaseui/StyledFirebaseAuth';

// Styles
import styles from './index.css'; // This uses CSS modules.
import './firebaseui-styling.global.css'; // Import globally.

//Components
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard';

// Instantiate a Firebase app.
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN
});

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    isSignedIn: undefined,

  };


  uiConfig = {
    signInFlow: 'popup',
    signInOptions: [
      firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    ],
    callbacks: {
      signInSuccessWithAuthResult: () => false,
    },
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unregisterAuthObserver = firebaseApp.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      this.setState({ isSignedIn: !!user });
      //User is signed in.
      console.info('User is signed in.');
      this.setState({providerData: user.providerData})   
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unregisterAuthObserver();
  }

  render() {
    return (  
      <div className={styles.container}>
        {this.state.isSignedIn !== undefined && !this.state.isSignedIn &&
          //Not signed-in yet
          <div>
            <Login />
            <StyledFirebaseAuth className={styles.firebaseUi} uiConfig={this.uiConfig}
              firebaseAuth={firebaseApp.auth()} />
          </div>
        }

        {this.state.isSignedIn &&
          //Signed in
          <div className={styles.signedIn} id="content-wrap">
            <Dashboard providerData={this.state.providerData} />
            <button><a className={styles.button} onClick={() => firebaseApp.auth().signOut()}>Sign-out</a></button>   
          </div>
        }   
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Dashboard.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Dashboard extends Component {

    state = {
        newEntry: false,
        newEntryButton: true,
        habitData: [],
        hamburgerOpen: false,
        checkIn: false,
        habitExist: false,
        user: '',
    };


    componentDidMount = () => {

          console.log(this.state.providerData[0].email )

        }




    render() {
        return (
            <div id="content-wrap">

                <h1>test</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

I want to put `pgamble@gmail.com` in the console.

If I remove that console line that props are populated:

[image]

Comment: Asked same question/problem is a different way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55904459/passing-props-to-componentdidmount

Answer (score 0):

In Dashboard, shouldn't it be accessed via this.props instead of this.state?