# passing props to componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, react-props

Able to render props in my Dashboard component, unable to pass this to componentDidMount for further ajax processing.

Render is working fine and display information.

I am using firebase and that's working correctly.

App.js

```
// React core.
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard';

class App extends Component {

 //firebase...

  state = {
    isSignedIn: undefined,
    displayName: undefined,
    email: undefined
  };

  componentDidMount() {

      this.setState({providerData: user.providerData}) 
      this.setState({ displayName: user.providerData[0].displayName })  
      this.setState({ email: user.providerData[0].email })   
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <div className={styles.container}>
        {this.state.isSignedIn !== undefined && !this.state.isSignedIn &&
          //Not signed-in yet
          <div>

            <Login />

          </div>
        }

        {this.state.isSignedIn &&
          //Signed in
          <div>
            <Dashboard 
              displayName={this.state.displayName} 
              email={this.state.email} />

          </div>
        }   
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Dashboard.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


class Dashboard extends Component {


    componentDidMount() {
        var thisComponent = this
        console.log(thisComponent.props.email)
    }

    render()  {
        const email = this.props.email

        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello, {this.props.displayName}!</h1>
                <h2>Your email is: {email}</h2> 
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

The componentDidMount in Dashboard.js is what is tripping me up. Unable to send email value for further ajax process. 
Should be getting the email in console, instead, I'm getting "undefined".

[image]

Comment: Are you definitely passing the `email` prop to this component when it first mounts?

Comment: can you share how you are passing props Example:- <Dashboard email="value" displayName="value" />

Comment: Yes, it does display in the <h2> tag as intended... but unable to ref again in the componentDidMount

Comment: Please show the code where you get the email and pass the email in props. With the current code, is impossible to solve your problem

Comment: create a constructor and `super(props)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only case where what is happening to you can happen is if `email` is comming from some asyncronous call. This is how it's happening:

1. `email` is an `undefined` state. But you make a asyncronous call to get `email`.
2. You render the components, but `email` is `undefined` because the asyncronous call isn't finished yet, so you console `undefined` in `componentDidMount`.
3. Then you get the result from the asyncronous call, setState of email, it goes down to props and it rerenders `Dashboard` with the correct email.

This way, you see email rendered but in `componentDidMount` it's undefined. It's rendering 2 times and only in the seconds time, after the component already mount, you are getting the correct `email`.

This is the only case where you can see the data, but it's undefined in `componentDidMount` and I'm almost sure that this is your case.

You provided almost no code to solve your problem, and the only thing I can do is give you the reason of your problem by doing some assumptions of your case. Hope this helps you understand your problem and solve it.

**Edit:** In your code, you are getting the email using firebase ( asyncronous call), so my assumptions are correct, now just need to know what is the expected results.

**Edit:**
If you need to do some action with email inside the component, use [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?utm_source=caibaojian.com#componentdidupdate)

For your case you can do

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  // Typical usage (don't forget to compare props):
  if (this.props.email != undefined && this.props.email !== prevProps.email) {
    // Do what you want with email
  }
}
```

Comment: This makes sense, how would I pass the value after the async render? (sorry no coffee yet :/)

Comment: what do you mean by `would do I pass the value after the async render` ? I can't understand your question.

Comment: fixed grammar on first comment

Comment: What do you want to do with `email` in `Dashboard` ? You can take a lot at [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html?utm_source=caibaojian.com#componentdidupdate)

Comment: I need to make an axios call eventually in the componentDidMount using the email value.

Comment: @Just edit, take a look. You will need to use `componentDidUpdate`